# Sumar valor de una columna al añadir filas al datagridview c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

Tengo el siguiente **código** en el botón añadir:

```
     int sumatoria;
     private void btnAñadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count <= 9 )
            {

                this.dataGridPre.Rows.Add(txtCodigo.Text, Cod_Pac_Bus, txtPac.Text, Cod_Odont_Bus, lblOdont.Text, lblCedula.Text, cmbDent.Text,
                    cmbPieza.Text, cmbTratamiento.Text, txtValor.Text, txtPorDes.Text, txtDscto.Text, txtTotal.Text);
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridPre.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    sumatoria = sumatoria + int.Parse(dataGridPre.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
                }             
                txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumatoria);

                dataGridPre.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
                cmbDent.Select();
            }
            else if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count > 9)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se Puede Añadir Mas Registros", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                btnGuardar.Select();
            }
        }
```

El cual como ven me permite ingresar una fila al `datagrid` cada vez que de *clic* en añadir y a su vez realizar la sumatoria de la columna numero 9 que contiene el valor de los totales.

Al momento de que se ejecuta el código en la primera interacción el resultado se muestra tal cual , pero al momento de añadir la segunda fila es como si me lo sumara 3 veces , 
**razón por la cual vengo a pedir ayuda para saber que estoy realizando de manera errónea**.

.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo suma varias veces porque defines incorrectamente el ambito de la variable `sumatoria`, debes ponerla dentro del evento click y no por fuera.

Ademas para sumar podrias usar `linq` qudando el codigo mas simple

```
private void btnAñadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            

    if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count > 9)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se Puede Añadir Mas Registros", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        btnGuardar.Select();
        return;
    }

    this.dataGridPre.Rows.Add(txtCodigo.Text, Cod_Pac_Bus, txtPac.Text, 
                                Cod_Odont_Bus, lblOdont.Text, lblCedula.Text, cmbDent.Text,
                                cmbPieza.Text, cmbTratamiento.Text, txtValor.Text, 
                                txtPorDes.Text, txtDscto.Text, txtTotal.Text);

    int sumatoria = dataGridPre.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Cells[9].Value.ToString()));
    txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumatoria);

    dataGridPre.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
    cmbDent.Select();
}
```

Comment: Gracias Leandro, efectivamente como tu indicas era la manera correcta de realizarlo.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de entrar al ciclo for, debes inicializar la variable sumatoria con 0 (como no la veo definida en la función, supongo que está definida a nivel de clase).

```
 private void btnAñadir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count <= 9 )
    {

        this.dataGridPre.Rows.Add(txtCodigo.Text, Cod_Pac_Bus, txtPac.Text, Cod_Odont_Bus, lblOdont.Text, lblCedula.Text, cmbDent.Text,
            cmbPieza.Text, cmbTratamiento.Text, txtValor.Text, txtPorDes.Text, txtDscto.Text, txtTotal.Text);
        sumatoria = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridPre.RowCount; i++)
        {
            sumatoria = sumatoria + int.Parse(dataGridPre.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString());
        }             
        txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumatoria);

        dataGridPre.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        cmbDent.Select();
    }
    else if (dataGridPre.Rows.Count > 9)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se Puede Añadir Mas Registros", "Alerta", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        btnGuardar.Select();
    }
}
```

Además, la línea

```
txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(suma);
```

me parece que debe ser

```
txtSubTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(sumatoria);
```

Comment: Un pequeño error al momento de copiar el código, lo edite y como ve estaría igual que las correcciones que me indico pero aun así no consigo que me arroje el resultado deseado ejemplo si ingreso 9000 al poner 2 filas me arrojas 27000